# How to connect two unrelated lists in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two lists of numbers that are related, but not by any mathematical relationship. One represents a process and another is time. For example:

1   |  .28

2   |  .56

3   |  .83

4   | 1.39

I'd like to have an excel program where you put the first number in a cell and it's corresponding second column number pops up in the next cell. Since they aren't related with an equation I need to implement some kind of 'if this, output this' command. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the time required by each process, you can create a lookup table and use VLOOKUP():

[image]

The formula in F13 looks up the value of E13 in the first column of the lookup table (E2:F10) and returns the corresponding value in the second column of the lookup table.

Here is more information [about VLOOKUP()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).